# How fetch text from NSString

Tags: nsstring

I have `NSString *searchResult` with text (cityId, name, lat, lon, country) like this :

```
6058560 London  42.983391   -81.233040  CA
```

How to fetch this values from string (need separated objects).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at using `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` with the white space character set.